# How to send ios silent push notification to Notification Hub with SendNotificationAsync method

Tags: swift, xamarin.forms, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I have working solution which sends push notification to NotificationHub from backend and then to Xamarin.Forms app. This works fine if payload contains "alert". I would like to implement silent push notifications. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) says that payload needs to contain "content-available" : 1 and no alert, badge or sound. Also you need to add to header `"apns-push-type" = "background"` and `apns-priority` to header.

**Expected result:**
I would like to send send silent push notification to NotificationHub using the method SendNotificationAsync.

**Actual result:**
I am only able to send it with SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync.

I tried add content-available to header or to add this to templateParameters Dictionary. You can find this code at very bottom of this post. I also tried registering the payload structures in different ways:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1,
       "acme1" : "bar",
        "acme2" : 42
   },
}
```

or

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

All these definitions worked for my backend if I sent pn with SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync but not with SendNotificationAsync.

**Registering device to NotificationHub**

```
var hub = new SBNotificationHub("blah", "blah");
var deviceToken = GetToken();
string jsonBodyTemplate = "{\"aps\":{\"#(content_available)\":1, \"notificationtype\":\"$(notificationtype)\", \"extra\":\"$(extra)\"}}";
string expiryTemplate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(10).ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
var tags = new NSSet(categories.ToArray());
await hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken);
await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags);
await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(deviceToken, IOS_TEMPLATE_NAME, jsonBodyTemplate, expiryTemplate, tags);
```

**Sending push notification to NotificationHub**

```
Dictionary<string, string> templateParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
templateParameters["notificationtype"] = "blah";
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "apns-push-type", "background" }, { "apns-priority", "5" }, { "content-available", "1" } };

var notification = new TemplateNotification(templateParameters);
notification.Headers = headers;
await hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I have an issue in registering user to NotificationHub. The *"content-available":1* part should be defined like in the code bellow:

```
string jsonBodyTemplate = "{\"aps\":{\"content-available":1, \"notificationtype\":\"$(notificationtype)\", \"extra\":\"$(extra)\"}}";
```